# How to get all websphere application configuration using Jython?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I need to collect all the WAS configuration detail in json format. I thought of using Jython for that. Can you please help how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality doesn't exist in WAS. The closest you will come is by using wsadmin to [extract the configuration to a properties file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_7extractprops.html). If you then need that in JSON you will have to convert it manually. Note that properties-based configuration doesn't include some configuration in the cell.